# Direct3D 11. GenerateMips not work

Tags: directx, directx11, mipmaps

I try use this

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc{};
desc.Width  =   texture->width;
desc.Height =   texture->height;
desc.SampleDesc.Count   =   1;
desc.Format =   DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
desc.BindFlags  =   D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
desc.MiscFlags  =   D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_GENERATE_MIPS;
desc.ArraySize  =   1;
desc.MipLevels  =   1;
desc.Usage  =   D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = {};
initData.pSysMem     =  data32; // unsigned int image buffer
initData.SysMemPitch =  texture->width * 4;
initData.SysMemSlicePitch = texture->width * texture->height * 4;

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc = {};
SRVDesc.Format = desc.Format;
SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = -1;

this->m_d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D( &desc, initData, &this->m_texture2d );
this->m_d3d11Device->CreateShaderResourceView( this->m_texture2d, &SRVDesc, &this->textureResView );
this->m_d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource( this->m_texture2d, 0, 0, data32, initData.SysMemPitch, initData.SysMemSlicePitch );
this->m_d3d11DevCon->GenerateMips( this->textureResView );
```

No effect.

Comment: What do you want to do and what result do you get?

Comment: Note that you are ignoring all the ``HRESULT`` return values which makes it extremely difficult to debug Direct3D/COM programming. If the function return value can be safely ignored, it would return ``void``. See [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

Answer (score 2):

```
desc.MipLevels  =   1;
```

You asked for the texture to be created with only one mip level, so the texture was created with only one mip level.

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476253(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The maximum number of mipmap levels in the texture. ..... 0 to generate a full set of subtextures.

So you almost definitely want to set this to 0 instead.

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc = {};
SRVDesc.Format = desc.Format;
SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = -1;
```

This isn't actually necessary for the simple case where your SRV accesses the entire texture; again, reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476519(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Set this parameter to NULL to create a view that accesses the entire resource (using the format the resource was created with).

You're creating the texture with initial data so you don't need this either:

```
this->m_d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource( this->m_texture2d, 0, 0, data32, initData.SysMemPitch, initData.SysMemSlicePitch );
```

Simplify your code, get rid of stuff you don't need, make sure that you ask for what you actually want, then it should work (and if it doesn't it will be easier for you to troubleshoot because there's less irrelevant code to distract you).

Comment: You might also consider using [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). The [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) and [WICTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/WICTextureLoader) modules both support auto-gen mips.

Comment: i used old tutorial. here new http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut05.html